# Calling web api from SPA giving error: Azure AD b2c

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication, pkce, azure-ad-b2c

Here is my aim: I would like to get an access token to call web api from my Spa application.

I created 2 azure b2c applications; one for web api and other for spa application(client).

I added scopes(api.read) by exposing api in web api application. I granted permission to these scopes from spa application.

I created one userflow with Sign up and sign in policy.

To generate the token, I used PKCE flow by getting auth code.

> POST
> https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/token
>
> grant_type: authorization_code
>
> client_id: api_appid
>
> scope: https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/web_api/api.read
>
> redirect_uri: https://localhost:435
>
> code:
>
> code_verifier:

The thing is I get the token but while calling the web api, it's giving error like:

```
Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you decode that token in jwt.ms and check if `scp` claim is present or not?

Comment: I cannot find either scp or role claims in decoded token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD B2C application for **Web API** and added scopes as below:

[image]

Now I created one SPA registration and added **API permissions** by granting ***consent*** like this:

[image]

I created **`Sign up and sign in policy`** and ran the user flow as below:

[image]

When I signed-in as a user it gave me **`auth-code`** in address bar like below:

[image]

***I generated the access token via Postman with parameters like this:***

```
POST  https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: SPA_appid
scope:  https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/web_api/api.read
redirect_uri: redirect_uri
code: code
code_verifier: code_verifier
```

[image]

**When I decoded the token, I got the `scp` claim successfully like below:**

[image]

Make sure to select Application as **`SPA App`** and resource as **Web_api** while running the user flow to get auth code.

While generating access token, you should give **`SPA_AppId`** in client_id parameter.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Any idea on how to get billing properties of b2c tenant?

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772627/fetch-billing-properties-of-azure-b2c-tenant-from-api?