# Fetch billing properties of Azure b2c tenant from API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-resource-graph

I have been working on b2c from a couple of weeks. I created many resources like applications, users, user flows, policies.

I want to know the billing details of this particular tenant.

I found this query where I can get charges list within a scope:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/charges?api-version=2021-10-01
```

Any way to filter this query so that it shows details only related to b2c tenant

But I'm not sure whether this is correct or not. Can anyone with this domain knowledge help me out whether I'm on right path or any modifications needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **billing properties** of your B2C tenant, you need to use query like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/{resourceName}?api-version=2019-01-01-preview
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Make sure to enable **`tokens`** if you are using ***implicit flow*** to acquire access token like below:

[image]

To get the access token, I made **`Authorization request`** in **browser** like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=74b2a1ba-xxxx-4xxc-axx1-c2xxxxxxxx
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

When I ran the above request, I got the token in the **address bar** as below:

[image]

I executed the query via ***Postman*** and got the ***billing properties of my*** **`B2C tenant`** successfully like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/{b2ctenantdomain}?api-version=2019-01-01-preview
```

**Response:**

[image]

##### UPDATE

To get the details like the **`resource group`** in which B2C tenant is created, you can run below **PowerShell** command:

```
Get-AzResource -Name tenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any idea on getting resource group in which b2c tenant is created from powershell Or rest api?

Comment: Please check the updated answer